# How to send a message of different lengths without trailing bytes \x00?

Tags: c++, zeromq

What does `20` inside `message()` mean vs the `20` after `message.data(),` in the below code?

```
zmq::message_t message(20);
snprintf ((char *) message.data(), 20 ,"%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity);
publisher.send(message);
```

From reading the documentation, `message(20)` initialises the message to be 20 bytes long. What does the `20` after `message.data(),` do?

How to change the size of the message to send the message without trailing bytes `\x00`? Can `"%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity` be declared outside and the length of that variable be used to initiate the message and send it?

Comment: *"What does the 20 after message.data(), do?"* Did you read the documentation for the `snprintf()` function?

Comment: Thank you, I read it then http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/. That means that if the user intends to send the whole message, the size e.g. `20` needs to be identical in both `message()` and `snprintf()`, is that correct?

Comment: The argument to `snprintf()` is designed solely to keep `snprintf()` from overflowing the allocation it is writing to. That is to say, if it were otherwise to write more than 20 characters, telling it that it may only write 20 will cause it to stop early. (Consider the case where `temperature` and `humidity` each have 7+ digits -- the message won't be big enough to hold the formatted text, and writing beyond the end of the buffer causes undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `snprintf()` with a limit of zero to measure how large the data will be before allocating the space for it:

```
auto length = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity) + 1;
// +1 to account for null terminating character.

zmq::message_t message(length);

std::snprintf(
    static_cast<char *>(message.data()), length,
    "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity
);

publisher.send(message);
```

You could also format into a local buffer that you know is large enough, measure the string's length, then copy it:

```
char buffer[64];

auto length = std::snprintf(buffer, 64, "%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity) + 1;

zmq::message_t message(length);

std::copy(buffer, buffer + length, static_cast<char *>(message.data());

publisher.send(message);
```

Comment: Is there any way to assign `"%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity` to a variable first and then compute the length? Would that be more efficient? That is, does `"%05d %d %d", zipcode, temperature, relhumidity` get evaluated twice? And would the cost of evaluating it twice be higher than assigning it to a variable and fetching that variable?

Comment: @Dave Which approach you use depends on how much variance the formatted message might have. For example, if you are including variable-length strings. Basically, you can only use a statically-sized local buffer if you know for sure the string will fit in it.

Comment: There are about 15 variable-length strings totalling from 150 to 200 bytes once formatted in a single string.

Comment: @Dave You could use an `std::ostringstream` instead, but that might wind up being slower. You would have to test.